# php 2 classes of the same namespace showing class not found

Tags: php, namespaces

I have this Project Structure:

```
BackTest
|MVC
||Controller.php
||View.php
||Model.php
```

Now when I create the 3 classes

```
Controller.php:
namespace MVC;
class Controller{}
$mdl=new Model();

View.php:
namespace MVC;
class View{}

Model.php:
namespace MVC;
class Model{}
```

In the Controller.php file when I am trying to instantiate a Model class I am receiving the error `Class 'MVC\Model' not found in` even though both of them are in the same name space what could the reason be?

maybe I need an autoload function ?

Comment: I am not sure about the files' contents, but you certainly need to include the appropriate file when using the class from that file. Can be direct including or via autoloading.

Comment: does it mean that if 2 files are in the same namespaces nevertheless i should require them ?? then what is the use of namespace beside avoiding conflicts between class names ?

Comment: via namespaces you can define how to find the proper file dynamically in a more or less flexible and easy way. To be strict with your particular question: you don't if they are defined in the same file. But I hope that's not the case )))

Comment: besides that namespaces usage is not about conflicts only. It also about organizing, structuring and etc.

Comment: Thanks You're great !